# Appending to JSON object in loop overrides values to last read value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I am trying to convert a List in the below from

```
[
  [ { 'loadBalancer' : 'LBValue'},
    { 'targetgrp' : ['tg1', 'tg2','tg3']} 
  ]

]
```

To

```
[
   {'loadBalancer' : 'LBValue',
    'targetgrp' : 'tg1'
    },
   {'loadBalancer' : 'LBValue',
    'targetgrp' : 'tg2'
   },
   {'loadBalancer' : 'LBValue',
    'targetgrp' : 'tg3'
   },
]
```

I tried below code at my end to process through the loop.

```
albtglist = [[ { 'loadBalancer' : 'LBValue'},
   { 'targetgrp' : ['tg1', 'tg2','tg3']} ]]


finalformattedData = []
data = {}

for x in albtglist:
  for x2 in x:
      if 'loadBalancer' in x2:
          data['albarn'] = x2['loadbalancer']
      if 'targetgrp' in x2:
          for tg in x2:
             data['tgarn'] = tg
             arndata.append(finalformattedData)

print(finalformattedData)


output: [ {'loadbalancer' : 'LBValue', 'targetgrp' : 'tg3'}, {'loadbalancer' : 
'LBValue', 'targetgrp' : 'tg3'} , {'loadbalancer' : 'LBValue', 'targetgrp' : 
'tg3'} ]
```

Not sure why the value of the tagetgrp is ovverriddn to the last value read. While prinitng th data in between I see the value was written correctly but coming out of the loop its getting overridden.

Comment: the json code is wrong format

Comment: Your code does not run as provided. `loadbalancer` != `loadBalancer`, `arndata` is not defined. This makes it hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. your albtglist is wrong format
2. you can use zip_longest in itertools to produce the tuple to make the new dict

```
from itertools import zip_longest

albtglist = [{'loadBalancer': 'LBValue'},
             {'targetgrp': ['tg1', 'tg2', 'tg3']}
             ]

finalformattedData = []
for load, target in zip_longest([albtglist[0]["loadBalancer"]], albtglist[1]["targetgrp"], fillvalue=albtglist[0]["loadBalancer"]):
    finalformattedData.append(
        {
            "loadBalancer": load,
            "targetgrp": target
         }
    )

print(finalformattedData)
```

ouput

```
[{'LoadBalancer': 'LBValue', 'targetgrp': 'tg1'}, {'LoadBalancer': 'LBValue', 'targetgrp': 'tg2'}, {'LoadBalancer': 'LBValue', 'targetgrp': 'tg3'}]
```

Comment: I am looking for having the load balancer value added with every target grp. Also I have updated the input on the albtglist.

Comment: @siri is the output not your wanted?

Comment: Seems like they are not looking for `LoadBalancer': None` in any of the results.

Comment: @XiaominWu I see none printing in the output but instead need the LB value printed too.

Comment: I think that's the point: `LoadBalancer': None,` is in your solution, but not in the OP's desired result.

Comment: @Mark thank you, i get the point. zip_longest has a param fillvalue may fix this

Comment: @siri i get the point. zip_longest has a param fillvalue may fix this, I have fixed the solution